# Wordpress full screen image and audio playing during 5 second

Tags: wordpress

I have a door on my website, when i click 'enter' then it display an image on full screen and audio playing during 5 second then access main page of my website.

I use Wordpress.

How do you do that?

Comment: removed thanks noise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the image and the sound you could easily adjust the image with css as so: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ for the audio you could add an audio element with the desired media. and hide it. when it stopped playing you could redirect easily with javascript/jquery. You may need to look for your template files in wordpress to add this elements.

Comment: Can you display on Full Screen the image, browser on full screen?

Comment: I haven't done something like that yet but this looks useful for your case full screen web browser: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/fullscreen-websites/